# How to convert date time into unix epoch value in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, unix-timestamp

How do I convert the following format to UNIX timestamps?

A value like: `01-02-2015 10:20 PM` should be converted to: `1418273999000`

I did try `to_timestamp` function but its not working for me.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

If your data is stored in a column called ts, in a table called data, do this:

```
select extract(epoch from ts) from data
```

Comment: It's all in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT

Comment: How fast is it?

Comment: Its not slow at all, unnoticable slow down if any. Either way it has to do something to convert the time to something usable, and likely it's stored in something more similar to epoch/unix format as opposed to hh:mi:ss or whatever.

Answer (score 20):

To add Joe's answer, you can use `date_part`, i think it's syntax is clearer than 'extract'.

`select date_part('epoch', ts) from data;`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to haoming answer,
for UNIX epoch this was my approach.
I also added a 180 day interval which can be changed/removed upon requirements.

> date_part('epoch', (column_name + INTERVAL '180 day')) * 1000