# ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone / integer

Tags: postgresql

When I want to divide a time into integer I get this error: `ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone / integer`.

Is there any function in postgres to divide the time to the integer?

For example: `"2013-11-14 07:46:15+03:30"` is the timestamp with time zone and I want the output of `"2013-11-14 07:46:15+03:30" / 2 = "1991-12-08 17:38:07.5+03:30"`

Comment: So what is the expected output of `2021-04-16 09:26:55 / 42`?

Comment: I want a time as output.

Comment: You probably want a TIME or INTERVAL datatype, instead of a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE. You can cast your TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE to TIME without any problems, just use CAST()

Comment: That result makes zero sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way for that question:

`SELECT to_timestamp(extract(epoch from DATE)/2) AS date FROM Table`

Where DATE is your timestamp with time zone and Table is your given table.
The type of result is a timestamp with time zone.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that it is not being stored as a number. If I understand what you are asking, you want the time since epoch instead of something like `01/01/1992`.

[How to convert date time into unix epoch value in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27740363/how-to-convert-date-time-into-unix-epoch-value-in-postgres) discusses a few ways to convert it to epoch, but the key ones are either `select extract(epoch from ts) from data` or `select date_part('epoch', ts) from data;` where `data` is your table, and `ts` is your timestamp. Then you should be able to divide by an Integer.

Comment: Even if you convert it to unix epoch, what sense does it make to divide a timestamp by an integer. I would be very interested in what the expected result of `2021-04-16 09:26:55 / 42` is supposed to be

Comment: My understanding is that in epoch,  `2021-04-16 09:26:55` would become `1618590415` which should be divisible by an int

Comment: Yes, but what is the _meaning_ of dividing that with an integer? It simply doesn't make sense. Dividing it by e.g. 42 yields and epoch that is equivalent to `1971-03-23 01:57:47`

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying. I am curious on the why as well, but I think this should provide a solution to whatever they are trying to do.

Comment: So I am new to Stack Overflow, and I get that context is nice, but does the why really matter for a question like this? I ask since it has a clear problem statement of `Is there any function in postgres to divide the time to the integer?`

Comment: It's likely an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377)